# VBoxManage not working from Python

Tags: python, cmd, virtualbox

I want to delete a given virtual machine installed on VirtualBox (itself installed on Windows XP). When I run the command from `CMD` the deletion rus as I expect. But when I run this code:

```
import subprocess
myVM="windowsxp_1"
status = subprocess.call(["VBoxManage", "unregistervm", myVM, "--delete"])
```

The deletion is performed. However, **unlike** in the first case, **the name of the VM is still listed on the VirtualBox** interface. Why and how can I resolve this problem ?
Here are 2 pictures explaining what I said:

**Deletection is successful:**

[image]

**But the name of the VM is still listed on the VirtualBox:**
[image]
The result is the same when I use :

```
import os
os.system("VBoxManage unregistervm vmNameToDelete --delete")
```

Comment: Please try to come up with a better title for your question.

Comment: @tripleee You can edit the title. English is not my mother tongue. Sorry.

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem using Python run from the command line.  Try running your Python script from the command line to see if your IDE is affecting things.

Comment: @RossRidge Thank you VERY much ! You are right, the Eclipse IDE has something wrong because when I run the command on several ways within a Python program from CMD everything is perfect. The IDE is the problem, as you said. Thank you a lot. You can post your comment as an answer in order to mark this question as answered.

Comment: @RossRidge I can not vote for the moment but i will do it later because even if your answer may look simple, it saved me from facing lot of problems for the comping weeks.

Comment: That's ok. You get more reputation from an accepted answer than an up vote, so it doesn't make much difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce this problem using Python run from the command line. It appears your IDE may be affecting things. Try running your Python script from the command line to see it works there.

I'm not sure why running the script under your IDE that would cause it not to work. Maybe you've got two versions of VirtualBox installed on your machine and your IDE is using a different PATH and ends up using a different `VBoxManage`.

Comment: I think that, in general, IDEs cause problems with anything relying on I/O with a shell.